# WPF - MediaElement is not Loading Resources from Buid EXE

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015, mediaelement

I can Load File using External Files, Which are Not Resource of The Application.
but the Resources of The application is not Loading in The MediaElement.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1.
Application Build is .Net 4.0 Client with x86 Architecture.

Loading of Resource is Set in **"LOADING_Loaded()"** event.
It Needs to Be Working.
You can Test that External File is Loading Properly if you are going to Download The Project [Link at The Bottom of This Post].

---

**XAML  File:**

> ```
> <Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
>     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Application"
>     mc:Ignorable="d"
>     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="260" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
> <Grid>
>     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
>         <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
>     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>         <Button x:Name="BTN_OPEN" Click="BTN_OPEN_Click" Content="Open" Padding="4" Margin="4"></Button>
>         <Button x:Name="BTN_STOP" Click="BTN_STOP_Click" Content="Stop" Padding="4" Margin="4"></Button>
>     </StackPanel>
>     <MediaElement Name="LOADING" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" MediaEnded="LOADING_MediaEnded" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Loaded="LOADING_Loaded" />
> </Grid>
> </Window>
> ```

---

**C# File:**

> ```
>   using System; using System.Windows;
>   using Microsoft.Win32;
>   namespace TestApplication
>   {
>    public partial class MainWindow : Window
>    {
>        public MainWindow()
>        { InitializeComponent(); }
>
>     private void LOADING_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         Uri u1 = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestApplication;component/Loading_Black.wmv");
>         LOADING.Source = u1;
>         LOADING.Play();
>     }
>
>     private void LOADING_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         LOADING.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
>         LOADING.Play();
>     }
>
>     private void BTN_OPEN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
>         var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
>         if (result == true)
>         {
>             Uri u1 = new Uri(dlg.FileName);
>             LOADING.Source = u1;
>             LOADING.Play();
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void BTN_STOP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     { LOADING.Stop(); }
>   }
> }
> ```

**My Resource "Loading_Black.wmv" is in the Root Directory of the Application.**
I don't Have any Sub Directories in this Application.
I Can't Find What is The Problem..
Please Help Me Out...
**Thanks :)**

If You Wanna Download This Project, Here it is: [TestApplication](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52upw8gk5ezlo27/Test%20Application.zip?dl=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this path for your Resource Folder: "ms-appx:///Assets/Loading_Black.wmv"
Have a look to this video-tutorial:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-20-Playing-Video-and-Audio-in-a-MediaElement-Control

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks For Yor Reply  
But That is Not Working & will Not Ever  
That Syntex is For Windows Phone Packges  
It is Not Recognised by WPF Package

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
first change the properties of your video file 
in the file property, select under

1. "Build Action " to *"Content"* and
2. "Copy to Output Directory" either "*Copy Always"* or *"Copy if Newer"*.

then in .cs file,

```
LOADING.Source = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Loading_Black.wmv");
```

Comment: First of All Thanks for Trying  
But That wil not work with me  
I need that Resource File Inside the EXE, so after thr Release Build I Will not have to Carry THat File Externally  
Sorry if I Did Not Specified Tht Requirement in My Main Post